# Настройка проекта Visual Studio Ultimate

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio

В Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate есть что-нибуть похожое, что в билдере, а именно, опция "Version Info" и "Application", чтобы можно было изменить стандартную версию приложения и смена иконки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значения версии приложения и его иконка устанавливаются в файлах ресурсов проект. Например, для проекта sample в папке проекта будет файл sample.rc (sample.rc2). И там будут прописаны значения `FILEVER`, `PRODUCTVER` и т.д., которые и определяют версию приложения. Иконку приложения проще устанавливать в Resource View ( View -> Other Window -> Resource View).